# Round number to nearest non zero digit

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code to round a number down to the nearest non zero digit in a string, or if the digit is larger than 1 it would round to the second decimal place.
I have yet to find a way to do this without converting the number to a string and then using regex.

The end result of the number can be either a string or a digit, I kept it a string because i already converted it to one earlier in the method.

I am curious to know what **you** guys would do in this situation.
I am working with all kinds of numbers (1 -> 50,000+ (generally)), however I am also working with VERY small numbers (4.42223e-9)

As always,

Thank you for taking the time to reading and answering this. I look forward to everyone's responses and criticism

```
import re

def roundToNearestZero(number):
    number = abs(number)
    if number < 1:
        #number = re.match("^0\\.0*[1-9][0-9]", f"{abs(number):.99f}").group()
        str_number = f"{number:.99f}"
        index = re.search('[1-9]', str_number).start()
        number = f"{str_number[:index + 3]}"
    
    else:
        number = f"{number:,.2f}"
    
    return number

print( roundToNearestZero(0.0000001232342) )# 0.000000123
print( roundToNearestZero(1.9333) ) # 1.93
print( roundToNearestZero(-0.00333) ) # 0.00333
print( roundToNearestZero(-123.3333) ) # 123.33
```

Comment: Why would you do this in the first place? This is _not_ only a rounding function, since there is an `abs` in the mix.

Comment: @Reinderien Hi, thank you for the question. I am creating a price checker and some of the coins/tokens are fractions of pennies. Some could be: 0.000000000012313149 and i am only interested in rounding to the nearest non zero digit: 0.00000000001. the reason i have abs() is because some i am also checking the price change within the last 24 hours and the API I use sends back scientific notation (which is why i have {number.99f}and negative numbers (-0.00000000123 for example) abs(). The abs() is not required in this method. I hope this helps and explains things a little bit more

Comment: I'm afraid that this entire procedure has a bad-idea fragrance. If you're formatting these values for display only, there are better formats. If this is part of an analysis routine you probably shouldn't be rounding at all.

Comment: @Reinderien Yes its for display, could you tell me the better formats you're talking about? Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

**A few stylistic edits to consider**. Your code is generally fine. In the example below, I made some minor stylistic
edits: shorter variable names (because they are just as clear in context as the
visually-heavier longer names); direct returns rather than setting `number`;
and taking advantage of the built-in `round()` function where it applies. I
would also add some explanatory comments to the code, as illustrated below.
It needs some explanation, for reasons discussed below.

```
def roundToNearestZero(number):
    n = abs(number)
    if n < 1:
        # Find the first non-zero digit.
        # We want 3 digits, starting at that location.
        s = f'{n:.99f}'
        index = re.search('[1-9]', s).start()
        return s[:index + 3]
    else:
        # We want 2 digits after decimal point.
        return str(round(n, 2))
```

**The function is unusual**. Less convincing is the function itself. First, it's not a rounding operation:
it takes the absolute value, converts to string, and then it does some
rounding-adjacent things. If `number` is 1 or larger, the function actually
rounds (to 2 digits past the decimal). Otherwise, the function imposes a floor
operation (to 3 digits, starting at the first non-zero). The whole thing seems
like a conceptual mess, but I understand that you might be operating under some
odd constraints from your project that you cannot easily change.

**Choose a better function name**. At a minimum you should rename the function. Naming it according to
mathematical operations makes little sense due to its inconsistent and unusual
behavior. Instead you might consider a name oriented toward its purpose: for
example, `display_price()` or whatever makes more sense based on its role in
the project.

**Data-centric orchestration**. Finally, I would encourage you to adopt a more data-centric approach to working
on algorithmic code – while writing code, debugging it, and when asking people
for help. Here I'm talking about the orchestration code rather than the
function itself. The first thing I did when experimenting with your code its to
set up better orchestration:

```
# This is print-centric. As such, it's not very useful.

print( roundToNearestZero(0.0000001232342) )# 0.000000123
print( roundToNearestZero(1.9333) ) # 1.93
print( roundToNearestZero(-0.00333) ) # 0.00333
print( roundToNearestZero(-123.3333) ) # 123.33

# This is data-centric and thus amenable to efficient testing.
# Any bad edit I made to the code was quickly revealed, and I
# could easily add more test cases as I explored.

def main():
    TESTS = (
        (0.0000001232342, '0.000000123'),
        (1.9333, '1.93'),
        (-0.00333, '0.00333'),
        (-123.3333, '123.33'),
        (0.00000012032342, '0.000000120'),
        (-0.00000012032342, '0.000000120'),
        (-0.000000120999, '0.000000120'),
        (204.947, '204.95'),
    )
    for inp, exp in TESTS:
        got = roundToNearestZero(inp)
        if got == exp:
            print('ok')
        else:
            print('FAIL', (inp, got, exp))
```

Answer (score 3):

First recognize that this is not strictly a rounding problem, but a *formatting* problem. You're doing this strictly for the purposes of display, and so your method should be named as such.

Have a careful read through https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language . I think the `g` specifier would suit this application fine. I see no universe in which it's a good idea to hide the sign from the user, so don't apply `abs`.

```
for x in (
    4.42223e-9,
    0.0000001232342,
    1.9333,
    -0.00333,
    -123.3333,
    50_000,
):
    print(f'{x:+.3g}')
```

```
+4.42e-09
+1.23e-07
+1.93
-0.00333
-123
+5e+04
```

If you want slightly more nuanced formatting behaviour than what `g` can get you - if, for example, you want all quantities at 0.01 or above to be printed in fixed notation and all others in scientific - then you can have an `if` statement that selects between two different format specifiers, each with their own precision field; in any case you won't need to call `round` yourself because that's done by the formatting.